# VM Ubuntu Server 16.04 no network connection with static IP

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp

My Setup:

- Oracle VM Virtual Box running on a windows 7 box
- Virtual hosting is enabled in Windows Box BIOS

Steps taken:

1. With Dynamic IP assignment the the Ubuntu server can ping
   everything.
2. No computer is able to ping the server
3. Change IP to static editing the following

   sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

   ```
   iface enp0s3 inet static
   address 10.10.2.0
   netmask 255.255.252.0
   gateway 10.10.0.1
   dns-nameservers 10.10.2.248

   sudo ifdown enp0s3 && sudo ifup enp0s3
   ```

   sudo reboot
4. After changes, server can not ping anything other then itself.

Unfortunately I can not copy and paste the ifconfig or ip route list. I know all of the IP addresses I unputted are correct. 10.10.2.0 is free as well.

Comment: IS the VM set to NAT or bridged mode? IIRC the default NAT LAN range for Oracle VMs is 10.0.x.0/24 (where 'x' is the NIC number): are you sure you are assigning an address within the correct range?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks steeldriver! What fixed it was...

1. Turned off server
2. changed adapter from NAT to Bridged
3. Turned Server on
4. I was able to ping out but could not ping the computer
5. Changed the IP
6. Shutdown Server
7. Turned Server back on

After those steps I was able to ping both ways.